# Remap Copy and Paste shortcuts on a Mac

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Windows at work and a Mac at home. One of the biggest issues is the difference between the copy paste shortcuts on Windows vs the Mac i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on Windows and on the Mac its <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. Invariably its hard because of learnt motor skills where my hand always shapes itself to the Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> configuration(I have been using Windows longer)

I would like to remap the Copy and Paste to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on the Mac. Why?  Because the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is actually the key that corresponds to where the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is on Windows keyboards and since its the last edge key its easy to find.  I have tried [Double Command](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't seem to have an option of turning <kbd>Fn</kbd> to the <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using a combination of DoubleCommand and jtbandes hint from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/26954/how-can-i-remap-ctrl-h-in-mac-os-x/28035#28035). First check the function key acts as control key box in Double command.  Then save the file ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict with the contents

```
{"^c" = "copy:";}
{"^v" = "paste:";}
{"^x" = "cut:";}
```

After you logout and log back in you should be able to use fn-c to copy etc.  There are obvious drawbacks to this approach.  You have to explicitly define every command you want to use fn for and mapping to control and then fn is really hacky.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work another way.  At first I thought you might be able to select both the "command key acts as control key" check box and the "fn key acts as control key" but that didn't seem to work. Ditto for changing to control with Alex's method above.  I was also unable to find the modifier for assigning commands to fn, and Apple's documentation seems to indicate that it's done at a lower level than keybinding has access to.  If someone knows a better way of doing this I would love to see it.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I'm still looking for a silver bullet solution..

Comment: Not work for me in Mac os 10.11

Answer (score 159):

Go System Preference > Keyboard > keyboard shortcuts and set Application Keyboard Shortcuts > All Applications

Add shortcut

Copy ^C

Undo ^Z

Redo ^⇧Z

Cut ^X

Paste ^V

Select All ^A

Done :)

Comment: Read the question to the end.

Comment: worked like a charm for the actions listed.  Doesn't have a negative effect on RDP like remapping Command <-> Control buttons.

Comment: This is _the_ answer. Works on Mac, RDP, VMWare Fusion and Parallels.

Comment: This is amazing, and works very well for other applications as well. For example, in Chrome I can now manage tabs using the same shortcuts I use on my PC. I had been previously trying to do this through an extension, but this way is much more reliable. Thank you!

Comment: So happy! This works like a champ!

Comment: The question asked for the `fn` key, isn't this only for `control`?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, for some reason, it looks like it should, "Edit" lights up when I press ^A, but cursor just moves to the beginning, it doesn't select all.

Comment: It seems to work now after restart, at least in some places.. firefox still not working

Comment: In Mavericks, those shortcuts can be added here: 
`Launchpad` -> `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` tab -> select `App Shortcuts` in the left panel -> click the `+` icon.

Another shortcut to add: `Save ^S`.

Also, the above solution will not work in programs that change the menu text, like how Sublime Text changes the entry for “Undo"

Comment: @Drew, I noticed the Sublime Text problem with Undo too. The menu entry says Undo [previous action]. Do you think maybe we can use wildcards in the shortcut definition? Probably a new questions...

Comment: yes but some programs have pre-existing mappings for ctrl-c/ctrl-v on a mac. if you make ctrl-c/ctrl-v map to command-c/command-v then you will have an issue.

Comment: Q: what programs have pre-existing mappings for ctrl-c/ctrl-v on a mac?  Seriously...  if I knew, I could possibly arrange for a multi-step mapping to handle them.

Comment: A: Terminal maps Control-C on a mac. Although mapping the copy function to Control-C does not appear to affect the operation.

Comment: OMG... my life is going to be soooo much better now!

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution I found so far for the issues of passing from ubuntu to mac!

Comment: Some apps works fine, but my desktop does not.  I can select all by ^+A, but still copy by command+c

Comment: Good answer, but not exactly correct.  On Mojave (10.14) at least, you need to specify the menu commands as "Edit->Copy", "Edit->Cut", etc..  Also, the OP was asking to remap the function keys.  This does not seem to be possible with this method.

Comment: you can also add redo by: Redo ctrl+shift+z

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for Firefox, even if I set it for all apps.

Comment: Works for me!! And how about the `find` shortcut?

Comment: This doesn't work for all the apps but still pretty helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

You could try to map <kbd>Command</kbd> to the <kbd>Control</kbd> key, and vice-versa. It's much easier to do and, in my opinion, is almost identical to Windows keyboards.

Just go to System Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Keyboard. On the lower left side is a button, Modifier Keys... Just switch `Control` and `Command` around.

Comment: This has a bad effect if you RDP into Windows.

Comment: This is also not a good solution if you use a lot of Java apps in Mac (which typically use the <kbd>Control</kdb> key as it's used in windows) or if you use Terminal a lot, which also uses the <kbd>Control</kdb> in more traditional ways.

Comment: This also has the unfortunate effect of swapping ctrl+tab and command+tab.

Comment: This also totally breaks Vim.

Answer (score 10):

1 - Go to "apple"
2 - Go to "system preferences"
3 - Go to "keyboard"
4 - On "keyboard", go to the "keyboard" tab
5 - Go to "modifier keys.."
6 - Change the "Control ( ) Key" drop down box to "Command"
7 - Click "ok"
Done!

Now:

> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = copy
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = paste, and
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> = undo

Answer (score 3):

This is a more complete list based on the [awesome answer of arttioz](https://superuser.com/a/363355/900623)

Go System Preference > Keyboard > keyboard shortcuts and set Application Keyboard Shortcuts > All Applications

Add shortcut

- Copy ^C
- Undo ^Z
- Redo Shift-^Z
- Cut ^X
- Paste ^V
- Select All ^A
- Find... ^F

You might also want to add some application specific ones, like for Google Chrome:

- Paste and Match Style Shift-^V
- Use Selection for Find ^E
- Find Next ^G
- Find Previous Shift-^-G

You can find existing menu key shortcuts in an application's menu bar and rebind all of them using the exact names displayed there. You can also verify the change there.

Answer (score 2):

Try [IronAHK](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/). It's a complete rewrite of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which you can use to remap keys and make shortcuts.

Comment: It's not a complete rewrite - unfortunately far from it.  It may do what the OP wants however.

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not as easy as using 3rd party tooling, but in 10.6 Snow Leopard one can use the following AppleScript to send the existing Command-C or Command-V keys, and then add that script [to a key of your choice](https://superuser.com/questions/72468/how-can-i-program-the-function-keys-on-my-macbook/97813#97813).

Something like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using {command down}
end tell
```

(This won't let you use the *fn* key though.)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way as well

1. Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard tab -> Modifier keys`
2. Swap the `Control` and `Cmd` keys
3. Select `Ok`

Answer (score 1):

I use [the **arttioz** way](https://superuser.com/a/363355/205255), do it with Application Shortcuts, but it have some problem.

If I switch language to Chinese, the Menu Title need to use the Chinese word. :-(

Example:

- 拷貝 ^C
- 還原/還原輸入 ^Z
- 剪下 ^X
- 貼上 ^V
- 全選 ^A

Comment: I thought about this issue as soon as I read the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to install **Karabiner**.

After installation enable the Complex Modifications > PC Shortcuts List

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#pc_shortcuts-list-group

Comment: _Why_ do you think that your suggested app is the _best solution_? Have you tested yourself?

Comment: Yes, for me this is the best solution to work with. I use it right now. I tried solutions above but they don't work out the way I need (as a former Windows guy).

Comment: The best solution is to avoid Mac

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a desktop at work, you might want to try using command for a while. I've found my muscle memory now seems sensitive to the style of keyboard I'm typing on. It gets confused with laptops, though. And when I had to use the 1998 version of the Apple keyboard.

On the other hand, if you use a laptop, this is utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do any remapping you like with the application https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: In case the link goes dead, this app's name is `Karabiner`, previously `KeyRemap4MacBook`

Answer (score 0):

[image: image: added the shortcuts in mac preference]

[image: image: only partly works]

I added the shortcut in mac preference, but only partly works, why?

Comment: Consider adding description of the steps you are taking in the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

How to make shortcuts on MAC like Windows (copy, paste, undo and find)?

The FN key is the best option to use for the shortcuts to be like in Windows

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard tab -> Modifier keys (at bottom)
-> Change the Globe/FN key to "Command".

Then the FN key functions like the Command key...

I found this a better (for me) answer for this.... the solutions offered were either too difficult to implement (for me) or not what i want.

You can also change the Command key to function like the Globe to not loose the functionality (though i rarely need it)

Hope it helps others!
Stu

Comment: Note: the Fn location on the Mac is the same as the Ctrl location on Windows, thus the finger action is the same