# MacOS - How to add keyboard shortcuts while retaining original shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I use an external keybaord that is shared between a Mac and a PC using the Open Source Barrier software. It drives me nuts trying to switch between Command and Control when using copy/cut/paste keyboard shortcuts.

So I followed the instructions from this great [Super User Post](https://superuser.com/a/363355/32741) and I was able to get these shortcuts working.

`Control + C = Copy`

`Control + V = Paste`

`Control + X = Cut`

Just what I wanted except, that I still wanted the original shortcuts used on Mac as well

`Command + C = Copy`

`Command + V = Paste`

`Command + X = Cut`

In case my brain remembered I was on the Mac. I was surprised to find that by adding the shortcuts that it removed the built in shortcuts. Is there a way to keep both sets of shortcuts?

Comment: Is this an Apple keyboard or third-party?

Comment: Third Party. Logitech Craft via Bluetooth.