# Finder in MacOS does not recognize remapped copy/paste function

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

MacOS uses Command+C/V for copy and paste, but these commands can be remapped to Crtl+C/V as explained in other posts like [here](https://superuser.com/a/363355) by going to System Preference > Keyboard > keyboard shortcuts and set Application Keyboard Shortcuts > All Applications

This works fine for most applications except the Finder app, which ignores the changed shortcuts [as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WsFE.png).
It looks like this is due to the fact that in this case, it says `Copy "filename.ext"` instead off simply `Copy`. Is the Remapping of Keys really that "naive" that it just looks at the name of the command?

Is there any way to fix this issue in MacOS without relying on any third party remapping tool?

Thank you very much

The issue is also present in other custom applications, but I find it most annoying within Finder, because it is an integral part of MacOS that Apple has full control over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's that literal. It uses the command as shown in the menu.

As you've discovered, trying to remap global commands from  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  to  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  is going to be a tough chase - and really not worth the effort.

Long-term, it's better to just learn the paradigm.